# Reverse all the elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I can't use the reverse method because it can only be used if the array is completely filled. This array is only going to be filled partially so what should i do?
This is my code:

```
    if (mContactsIndex == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Array is empty");

    string tempContact;
    int ctr;
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < mContactsIndex; ctr++)
    {
        tempContact = mContacts[ctr];
        mContacts[ctr] = mContacts[mContactsIndex ];
        mContacts[mContactsIndex ] = tempContact;
        displayContacts();
    }
```

what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: I would suggest walking through a simple example on a whiteboard or something. I think that will make it evident what is wrong. Right off the bat I can tell you you are definitely not using `mContactsIndex` correctly.

Comment: How about `mContacts.ToList().Reverse().ToArray();`?

Comment: You are never changing this variable `mContactsIndex `

Comment: @SaeedNeamati What is complexity of your line of code?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, `mContacts.Reverse().ToArray()` would work as well, no need for `ToList`

Comment: Your array doesn't need to be full to use Reverse.

@SaeedNeamati List.Reverse() just uses Array.Reverse under the hood no converting to list is not helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an array that's partially filled, you might want to use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. It's like an array, but its size is variable.

If you do want to use an array, you can use [`Array.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z78xtwts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to reverse just the portion that you want to:

```
Array.Reverse(mContacts, 0, mContactsIndex);
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked, we haven't learned how to use array lists yet, so i don't know how to use that. But the array.reverse worked!